# Is a brute force UDP hole punch possible if both external IPs, and both internal ports are known to each client?

Tags: nat, security, ip, udp

So I was just reading about hole punch techniques for UDP and TCP. I read that TCP hole punch can easily be accomplished if a UDP connection has already been established. So here is my theoretical setup. I have two clients A and B both behind a NAT. They do not have a server to help them with the hole punch. Both have dynamic dns set up so that the other client can be hard coded to point to the others external address, also both are hard coded to use the same internal port, which we will say for example is 22321. Now these clients know that if they are both started and not connected that they want to connect so once every minute on the minute they send a UDP datagram to the other client to every single port, starting with the highest ports since my guess is a NAT will be inclined to use ports above 49152 as those are the dynamic ports. After each has done this there will be a record entered into the NATs state. If the clients are lucky then one of the two clients will hit the others external port after it has been opened by the NAT, and the datagram will get through and the listening client could then notify the sending client of the successful connection. If they were not so lucky then the clients just need to repeat the process, this time each starting from opposite ends to cut the time in half, when one gets through to the other then the receiver notifies the sender that the connection has been established. Could this methodology work? Or perhaps even be simplified by tracking the RST responses from the NAT?

We have clients A and B which are behind a NAT and want to communicate.  both clients are listening on UDP port 22321 and both clients know the others global IP address, we will say that A has an ip address of 1.1.1.1 and B has a global ip address of 2.2.2.2.  So A sends a packet to 2.2.2.2 on every single port, the contents of which need be basically nothing, for every single packet that passes through the NAT the NAT will change the outgoing IP from A's local address i.e. 192.168.1.16 to the global address 1.1.1.1. As the NAT forwards this packet to client B it creates a state entry for each of those packets so that if a packet is recieved from 2.2.2.2 on any of those ports it will know to forward it to client A (192.168.1.16) on port 22321. All of those packets would reach B's NAT at 2.2.2.2 and be discarded as unsolicited packets. Client B does the exact same process targeting client A's global ip address 1.1.1.1 when it hits a port on the NAT that client A has sent a packet out of to client B's NAT (basically any of them at this point) it will forward the packet on to client A. and Client A would be able then respond using that connection from then on out.  Now the problem with this is negotiating who goes first and then when the second client should start, so instead they both just start at the exact beginning of a minute and quite likely the first attempt will fail to yield a connection but if they both then immediately repeat the process then there should be 1 or likely even many successful connections, each client could then just discard all but the first connection that succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Yes it is possible. The network has to be able to handle all the packets (without exceptions - packet loss means death), the machines have to be able to send out packets fast enough, the other end must not have "flooding protection" and the address has to not change every time you open a new connection. This method managed to connect my laptop behind my University's WiFi with my friends laptop behind his WiFi and it sent a packet from my home WiFi through my University's symmetric NAT. If you're using a phone, you should probably send packets as fast as possible because phones are slow but with laptops you can synchronize the barrage of UDP packets with Thread.sleep()

```
/**
 * Shoots empty UDP packets at every port between "start" and "end".
 */
public static void sendBarrage(int start, int end, InetAddress target) {

    final ByteBuffer to_send = ByteBuffer.allocate(0);

    // Start at a random value to avoid re-traversing failed paths on repeated attempts.
    final int starting_point = start + generator.nextInt(end - start);

    // Go from starting_point down to 1024. 
    for (int port = starting_point; port >= start; --port) { 
        try {
            if (made_connection == false) {
                myChannel.send(to_send, new InetSocketAddress(target, port));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException cce) {
            Application.printerr("Channel closed while on port: " + port);
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Application.printerr("Error sending in port: " + port);
            continue;
        }
    }

    // Go from 65535 down to say starting_point, not including starting_point.
    for (int port = end - 1; port > starting_point; --port) { 
        try {
            if (made_connection == false) {
                myChannel.send(to_send, new InetSocketAddress(target, port));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException cce) {
            Application.printerr("Channel closed while on port: " + port);
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Application.printerr("Error sending in port: " + port);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

^ Make sure you call this method in a loop, it might take a few attempts. Keep in mind that this method does NOT work with cell phone tower networks (unless you get insanely lucky and the public ip address does not change). It might work better if one side holds the port open while the other guesses rather than having them both brute force both sides.

Also, if only one side holds the ports open, this method might be good: https://www.goto.info.waseda.ac.jp/~wei/file/wei-apan-v10.pdf

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I'm having trouble understanding why you would have to create 50,000 datagram sockets bound to 50,000 different ports, but it has been a while since I posted this and I don't deal with this stuff to often, mostly I do programming at the application layer, I'm going to thing about this some more now, and I'm happy someone besides me finds this interesting haha.  10 seconds to try everything isn't that bad for a worst case scenario on upload bandwidth since it only has do be done once per start up. If you try it out, please let me know how it goes.

Comment: If you don't bind a datagram socket to a port and someone sends a packet to that port, even  if you try to receive from that port after the fact, you won't get the packet they left. You have to bind first, then they send you the packet, then you receive. Or you can just wait (block) until the packet arrives, but with logistics like that, you don't have time to wait around.

Comment: Crap. Apparently I can only bind an application to 4092 ports. And any ports I'm not bind-ed to, any packets sent to those ports are thrown away. So it won't work (unless you keep binding,  unbinding, and resending to 4000 ports). Can I get best answer?

Comment: That is only true by default, You can actually change the MaxUserPorts setting in the registry to be able to bind to every single port, you will likely be getting the best answer yes. but it would be awesome if you try that really quick.  MSDN documentation on the registry key I am referring to can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938196.aspx

Comment: Listening on more than one address is not a good idea because symmetric NAT only accepts from the socket that it sends from, and you can't afford to send 65k packets from more than one local port. That being said, my code does brute force through my local network and is synchronized to shoot at every port each second. Note that depending on your computer and Wireless/Ethernet connection quality, it might take more than one second to hit every port.

Comment: Wait, why would you be listening on more than one address? More than one port, yes, but each application should only be listening on one address.

Comment: OK so I think you are over complicating what I was trying to suggest with my initial question, I edited the question and added a new paragraph, please give it a read and let me know what you think, my guess is the application you wrote could be quickly tweaked to better match up with what I was trying to describe.  Or perhaps there is a critical flaw in my logic that you will see right away that you could then inform me of.

Comment: Sorry, I meant port. Listening on more than 1 port is not a good idea because The port you are listening on has to hit all 65k of the other user's ports (symmetric NAT makes a new public port number and new connection for each port you use). So if you use 10 ports, you have to send 10*65k packets to break through.

Comment: That's what I was saying though, you just send out of one port, so it's 1 x how ever many ports you send to and like I said in my original question most NATs have a preferred range of ports they use because they don't want to use and reserved ports for their random use ports. so the theoretical standard use case scenario would actually require listening on far less than 65k ports.
The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) suggests the range 49152 to 65535 (215+214 to 216−1) for dynamic or private ports. So that would be only 16383 ports each NAT would be listening on.

Comment: >> Both clients are listening on UDP port 22321 -- It doesn't matter what port they listen on because the NAT will translate it into a random public port. >> Client B does the exact same process targeting client A's global ip address 1.1.1.1 when it hits a port on the NAT that client A has sent a packet out of to client B's NAT (basically any of them at this point). -- At this point client B has to hit each and every port that client A hit in order for 1 of the 65k ports to be a match. Each party sends 65k packets. System.currentTimeInMs() is international time, so they use it to synchronize.

Comment: 49152 to 65535 is far too small. My university's symmetric NAT is like 20k to 65k and my cell phone tower is like 1024 to 65k.

Comment: Realistically it would be like between 40k and 65k ports assuming that the NAT has a single public IP address. If it has more than 1 IP address, then it will actually switch IP addresses for multiple connections to the same device and you would have to hit all 65k ports on ALL the public IP addresses corresponding to that NAT (like for a cell phone tower, perhaps)

Comment: Also, if there are no available ports (i.e. 40k out of 65k ports are already in use and you need to request 65k additional ports), the ports that could not fit because the table was full - those ports are dropped - their packets don't go through.

Comment: So far I have only got it to work on local networks (in my home or within my university or on localhost).

Comment: Also, there's like a short window while the NAT flow is open to a response. You have to send from port X and get a reply to back to port X within the time-span of the window (like 300 ms or something like that) or else the response packet won't go through. And hitting all 65k ports takes a little more time than the window (700 ms on one desktop, 800 ms on another)

Comment: Right I knew about the window and I completely agree with you about the NAT having multiple global IPs, if the NAT has multiple global IPs then this method would be impossible. I'm thinking of this from a desktop computer at home behind a router to another at home user behind a router. Also, a lot of NAT's (from what I've read) will not even change the port if the port chosen is already in the ephemeral range. I may have time tonight to try it out myself.  what language did you right your tool in?

Comment: So I found out that my university's symmetric NAT has one private IP that starts with the number "10" but multiple public IP's (the pre-fix is always 128.227.*.*, though). Also, if you look at a pair of public and private addresses and port numbers, it looks like this: Private: "10.137.14.175:58614" ; Public: "128.227.12.8:58614", where the public port and the private port are always the same. Honestly, it looks like your best bet it to do regular STUN, but also guess maybe a couple hundred ports and maybe a few IP addresses above the one you got from the STUN server.

Comment: Also, I got the barrage method working from a computer with no NAT to a computer with symmetric NAT, but between two NATS, it just fails.

Comment: Also, if both sides have public ipv6 addresses, you don't need NAT traversal. Also, if only one side has both a public ipv6 and a public ipv4 address and your server has both ipv4 and ipv6, you can append a prefix to the ipv4 address and for the first packet it'll be like you're communicating ipv6 to ipv6 (after that you have a working DatagramSocket and can just go from there).

Comment: So in a sense, the only time where NAT traversal seems impossible is if neither side has IPV6 and both sides are behind a super beefy symmetric NAT. Like a cell phone tower where the port and address are random and follow no pattern.

Comment: That's seems like what I w was thinking when I posted the question, because what I'd read was that if your using a non reserved port number the NAT will often choose the same port and if not he same port it will still often be an ephemeral port making the range you'd have to guess very small. However if the NAT has multiple public IPs to choose from then this method be comes much harder if not impossible, even if you knew the different options. And I've already known that if either computer had a public IP then there was no need for hole punching at all and that would include IPv6 addresses th

Comment: I've given you the accepted answer, please update your answer to reflect your final discoveries so it is easier for any future visitors of the page to find.